# php reg ex for space and 4 digit

Tags: php, regex

I need to match the e.g " 2014"( xxxx) string in line, what I mean is:

space and fix 4 digit at the end of string

```
The Shawshank Redemption 1994 
The Godfather  1972
The Dark Knight  2008
Pulp Fiction  1994  
The Good, the Bad and the Ugly  1966 
Schindler's List 1993 
12 Angry Men 1957 
The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King 2003 
Fight Club 1999
```

i will use this with

```
$pattren='';
$replace=preg_replace($pattren, "", $input_lines);
```

first i try to use explode but it not works as i expected i have not good know how with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
$replace = preg_replace(/\s+\d{4}$/, "", $input_lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}\s?$
```

Try this. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/19

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() to remove white spaces from last. (this will remove any number of spaces)

```
 <?php
      $str = " The Shawshank Redemption 1994     ";
      $str = trim($str);
      echo $output = substr($str,-4);

 ?>
```